$\mathbb{N}$ is the smallest infinite set
We work in $\mathsf{ZF}$. Given sets $A, B \neq \emptyset$, we define the following relations:

$A <_{\text{inj}} B$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\exists f: A \hookrightarrow B$: $f$ is injective and $\not\exists g: B \hookrightarrow A$: $g$ is injective

$A <_{\text{surj}} B$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\exists f: B \twoheadrightarrow A$: $f$ is surjective and $\not\exists g: A \twoheadrightarrow B$: $g$ is surjective


We say that a set $C \neq \emptyset$ is finite if there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and a bijection $C \leftrightarrow \{1, \ldots, n\}$.
Say that a set $X \neq \emptyset$ is injectively small if we have $X <_{\text{inj}} \mathbb{N}$. Say that a set $X \neq \emptyset$ is surjectively small if we have $X <_{\text{surj}} \mathbb{N}$.
Can we show that there exists no infinite injectively small set $X \neq \emptyset$? Can we show that there exists no infinite surjectively small set $X \neq \emptyset$?
My attempt at a proof that there exists no infinite injectively small set $X \neq \emptyset$:
Assume that $X \neq \emptyset$ is infinite and injectively small, hence there is an injection $f: X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{N}$. Since $X$ is nonempty, let $n_1 = \operatorname{min} f(X)$ and $x_1 \in X$ with $f(x_1) = n_1$. Since $X$ is not in bijection with $\{1\}$, we have $f(X) \setminus \{n_1\} \neq \emptyset$. Let $n_2 = \operatorname{min} f(X) \setminus \{n_1\}$ and $x_2 \in X$ with $f(x_2) = n_2$. Since $X$ is not in bijection with $\{1, 2\}$, we have $f(X) \setminus \{n_1, n_2\} \neq \emptyset$. Let $n_3 = \operatorname{min} f(X) \setminus \{n_1, n_2\}$ and $x_3 \in X$ with $f(x_3) = n_3$. Continue inductively, obtaining a sequence $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ with distinct terms. Now, define $g: \mathbb{N} \hookrightarrow X, g(k) = x_k$. Since the terms of $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ are distinct, $g$ is injective (in fact bijective), a contradiction.
My attempt at a proof that there exists no infinite surjectively small set $X \neq \emptyset$:
Assume that $X \neq \emptyset$ is infinite and surjectively small, hence there is a surjection $f: \mathbb{N} \twoheadrightarrow X$. For each $x \in X$, set $n_x = \operatorname{min} f^{-1}(\{x\})$. Now, the mapping $x \mapsto n_x$ is an injection $X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{N}$, hence by an analogous argument there is a bijection $X \leftrightarrow \mathbb{N}$, contradicting our assumption.
Are these proofs correct? In particular, am I correct in that they do not depend on the axiom of choice in any way? Can we show that there is no infinite surjectively small set by directly exhibiting a surjection in the other direction and arriving at a contradiction?

You didn't use the axiom of choice; however, the second proof didn't use the fact that $X$ was infinite, but it concluded that $X$ is in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$ so it can't be complete as written.

@hunter The second proof is actually fine; the OP reduced it to the first case i.e. the OP demonstrated $X$ infinite surjectively small implies $X$ infinite injectively small
